# Spring-Boot and Hibernate issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am just building a new App based on Spring-Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE, Hibernate and Java 9.

Since last night I had some issues for what I just have rebuilt it again to find step by step where the problem is located.

I am constantly facing the same issue and I cannot fix it by myself.

**The Error:**

```
2018-07-19 10:32:38.949  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.tmtest.demo.DemoApplication          : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-MKTBJ7O with PID 9080 (D:\Git\test2\target\classes started by N-rG in D:\Git\test2)
2018-07-19 10:32:38.952  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.tmtest.demo.DemoApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-19 10:32:39.012  INFO 9080 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2c07545f: startup date [Thu Jul 19 10:32:39 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/N-rG/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-07-19 10:32:39.967  INFO 9080 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$53763105] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-07-19 10:32:40.174  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-07-19 10:32:40.198  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.198  INFO 9080 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
2018-07-19 10:32:40.207  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;D:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\N-rG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\N-rG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\N-rG\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\N-rG\AppData\Roaming\npm;.]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.279  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-07-19 10:32:40.279  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1272 ms
2018-07-19 10:32:40.372  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.372  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.372  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.372  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.372  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.372  INFO 9080 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.467  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-07-19 10:32:40.531  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2018-07-19 10:32:40.557  INFO 9080 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-19 10:32:40.566  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.603  INFO 9080 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.2.Final}
2018-07-19 10:32:40.604  INFO 9080 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-07-19 10:32:40.650  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2018-07-19 10:32:40.727  INFO 9080 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2018-07-19 10:32:40.838  WARN 9080 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.tmtest.demo.Backend.Factory.FactoryWorker.factoryPublisher in com.tmtest.demo.Backend.Factory.FactoryPublisher.factoryWorkerList
2018-07-19 10:32:40.839  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-07-19 10:32:40.849  INFO 9080 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-07-19 10:32:40.850  INFO 9080 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-07-19 10:32:40.860  INFO 9080 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-19 10:32:40.867 ERROR 9080 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.tmtest.demo.Backend.Factory.FactoryWorker.factoryPublisher in com.tmtest.demo.Backend.Factory.FactoryPublisher.factoryWorkerList
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.tmtest.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.tmtest.demo.Backend.Factory.FactoryWorker.factoryPublisher in com.tmtest.demo.Backend.Factory.FactoryPublisher.factoryWorkerList
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:782) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:733) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1664) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.2.Final.jar:5.3.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**My POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tmtest</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>10</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>    
</project>
```

**The FactoryPublisher class**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class FactoryPublisher {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "factoryPublisher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private final List<FactoryWorker> factoryWorkerList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final VirtualTimer virtualTimer = VirtualTimer.CounterFactory.getNewCounter();
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public FactoryPublisher() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            factoryWorkerList.add(new FactoryWorker());
        }
        new Thread(virtualTimer).start();
    }

    public synchronized void updateWorkers() {
        factoryWorkerList.forEach(factoryWorker -> factoryWorker.updateWorker(virtualTimer.getCurrentValue()));
    }
}
```

**and the Worker:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class FactoryWorker {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private long iD;


    public void updateWorker(final int timeData) {
        //System.out.println("worker: " + iD + " was updated with data: " + timeData);
    }
}
```

**the main:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is giving a hint already:

```
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.tmtest.demo.Backend.Factory.FactoryWorker.factoryPublisher in com.tmtest.demo.Backend.Factory.FactoryPublisher.factoryWorkerList
```

The `mappedBy` property can be used to define a bi-directional mapping, where you define the relation on one side (eg `@ManyToOne`) and use the `mappedBy` property on the other side so it knows how the relation works.

However, in your case you don't have a bi-directional mapping. In fact, you don't have a field called `factoryPublisher` in your `FactoryWorker` entity, so it can't resolve your mapping.

To solve this, you want to map the `factoryPublisher` field within `FactoryWorker`,  for example:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class FactoryWorker {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private long iD;
    // Add this
    @ManyToOne
    private FactoryPublisher factoryPublisher;

    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want a bi-directional mapping, you can remove the `mappedBy` property on `@OneToMany`.